# why my append function in linked list not working?

Tags: c

the programme have runtime error when it want to add nodes to linked list (in executing append function).

i tested 'create' and 'prepend' function  they do their parts correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Node {
    int data ;
    struct Node* next ;
};

struct Node* Head=NULL ;

struct Node* create(int ,struct Node*);
struct Node* prepend(int ,struct Node*);
struct Node* traverse(struct Node*);
struct Node* append(int ,struct Node*);

int main()
{
    int data =4 , i ;
    Head = prepend(data,Head);
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        scanf("%d",&data);
        append(data,Head);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

create func for adding new nodes

```
 struct Node* create(int data ,struct Node* Head){
        struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));
        if(newNode == NULL){
            printf("Error\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        newNode -> data = data ;
        newNode -> next = Head ;
        return newNode ;
    }
```

adding new node at the first of linked list:

```
struct Node* prepend(int data ,struct Node* Head){
        struct Node* newNode = create(data,Head);
        Head = newNode ;
        return Head ;
    }
```

for returning last created Node:

```
struct Node* traverse(struct Node* Head){
    struct Node* cursor = Head ;
    while(cursor->next != NULL || cursor->next != Head){
        cursor = cursor->next ;
    }
    return cursor ;
}
```

for adding new node to end of the linked list:

```
struct Node* append(int data ,struct Node* Head){
    struct Node* newNode = create(data,Head);
    struct Node* cursor = traverse(Head);
    cursor->next = newNode ;
    return newNode ;
}
```

Comment: `(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));` => `malloc(sizeof(struct Node));` or wrong malloc size

Comment: while(cursor->next != NULL || cursor->next != Head) change to while(cursor->next != NULL && cursor->next != Head)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this : 
`struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));`

to this:
`struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));`

The Segmentation Fault error comes from the traverse function and in the while's condition. It seems that NULL value can not be used in comparison and I now wonder why! By the way change this function as follow then try again:

```
struct Node* traverse(struct Node* Head){
  struct Node* cursor = Head ;    
  while(cursor->next){
      if(cursor->next == Head)
          break;
      cursor = cursor->next ;
  }
  return cursor ;
}
```

Comment: I added another aspect of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

you're not allocating enough bytes with

```
   struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));
```

`sizeof(struct Node *)` is the size of a pointer, and your structure holds a pointer + another field, so that's undefined behaviour.

a correct way (using `sizeof` on the dereferenced pointer to get the proper size & not casting the return value of `malloc`):

```
   struct Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
```

the second issue is in your `traverse` function. When you do `cursor = cursor->next`, `cursor` can be `NULL` and you're testng `cursor->next` at the next iteration. Just iterate on the list & memorize the last non-`NULL` node instead (and drop the test for `Head` being the next element, because it's just not possible:

```
struct Node* traverse(struct Node* Head){
    struct Node* cursor = Head;
    struct Node* retval = cursor;
    while (cursor != NULL) {
        retval = cursor;
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: your traverse function was also wrong. I didn't test, but I think this is better.

Comment: it's stuck in a inf loop.